# how to find the least two column values in a table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, wampserver

I have table records in an example below:
name  | grade1 | grade2 | grade3 | grade4  | least_two |
johny |     30     |    20     |     10    |     15     |                 |
fredd |     25     |    40     |     30    |     35     |                 |
I want an sql query which can find and sum the least two values of the 'four grade columns' and the result updated to the last column.
like in this example below:

name  | grade1 | grade2 | grade3 | grade4  | least_two |
johny |     30     |    20     |     10    |     15     |       25       |
fredd |     25     |    40     |     30    |     35     |       55       |

the least two column values in the first row are :10 and 15. so the last column has a value of 25
and the least two column values in the second row are 25 and 30. it's last column has a value of 55.

the table name is 'student_grades'.I am using wampserver. how do I write an sql statement to achieve this.

this is the sql query that worked for sqlite :

```
 try{
    String sql = "update sudent_grades set least_two=(SELECT MIN(grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4) + " +
"( SELECT  grade1 AS s FROM sudent_grades t2 WHERE sudent_grades.name = sudent_grades.name UNION ALL " +
"  SELECT  grade2 FROM sudent_grades t2 WHERE sudent_grades.name = sudent_grades.name UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  grade3 FROM sudent_grades t2 WHERE sudent_grades.name = sudent_grades.name UNION ALL" +
"  SELECT  grade4 FROM sudent_grades t2 WHERE sudent_grades.name = sudent_grades.name ORDER BY s LIMIT 1,1" +
") AS result WHERE name = student_grades.name )";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
 
   }catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }finally{
           try{
              rs.close();
              pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
```

but it doesnt work for mysql server.

Comment: Fix your data model!  The values should be in separate rows.

Comment: Also note: this place is not a "here my requirements, now what" place. We **help** you solving your problems, we dont solve them for you. Thus: please include your own efforts, otherwise most people will not bother looking at your input.

Comment: please how do you mean? there are two rows in each table. kindly explain further @GordonLinoff

Comment: I think you should have mentioned that you are talking about **the sum of the two least values per row**. It's not really obvious from a first glance... And I think it is not trivial to find out the two least values of a bunch of columns, sum them and put them into the very same result row.

Comment: Try adding an SQL query you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the data and then reaggregate:

```
select name, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4,
       sum(case when seqnum <= 2 then grade end) as least_two;
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by grade) as seqnum
      from ((select t.*, grade1 as grade
             from t
            ) union all
            (select t.*, grade2 as grade
             from t
            ) union all
            (select t.*, grade3 as grade
             from t
            ) union all
            (select t.*, grade4 as grade
             from t
            ) 
           ) t
      ) t
group by name, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4;
```

The data should be stored with one row per name and grade -- and perhaps additional information such as the `datetime` for the grade.

Comment: ohk thank you. will try it out